# converting a DocumentTermMatrix to factor

Tags: r

I have variable with type of DocumentTermMatrix, and I want to replace any element of it by zero and one(if element value > 0 is equal to 1 and if not is equal to 0)

I wrote the following function:

```
yes_or_no = function(x)
{
  y = ifelse(x>0 , 1,0)
  y = factor(y , levels = c(0,1) , labels = c("no","yes"))
  y
}
text_train = apply(text_freq_word_train, 2,yes_or_no)
```

the output doesn't seem to be correct.

```
head(inspect(text_freq_word_train)) = 

<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 7168, terms: 2114)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 64968/15088184
Sparsity           : 100%
Maximal term length: 13
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
Sample             :
      Terms
Docs   job million obama percent presid say state tax vote year
  1281   0       3     0       2      1   1     7   2    2    3
  1619   0       0     0       0      0   0     0   0    0    0
  2143   3       0     2       0      3   0     0   0    0    1
  356    0       0     0       0      0   0     1   0    1    0
  3928   0       1     0       0      0   0     0   0    0    1
  3987   0       0     0       0      0   3     0   0    0    0
  428    4       0     0       0      0   0     0   0    0    0
  5157   0       0     0       0      0   0     0   1    0    1
  5532   0       0     0       0      0   1     1   2    1    0
  6120   1       0     2       0      4   2     0   0    0    0
      Terms
Docs   job million obama percent presid say state tax vote year
  1281   0       3     0       2      1   1     7   2    2    3
  1619   0       0     0       0      0   0     0   0    0    0
  2143   3       0     2       0      3   0     0   0    0    1
  356    0       0     0       0      0   0     1   0    1    0
  3928   0       1     0       0      0   0     0   0    0    1
  3987   0       0     0       0      0   3     0   0    0    0

head(text_train) = 



    Terms
Docs abort anni  demand group list  polit say   support third trimest
  1  "YES" "YES" "YES"  "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES"   "YES" "YES"  
  2  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"   "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"    "NO"  "NO"   
  3  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"   "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"    "NO"  "NO"   
  4  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"   "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"    "NO"  "NO"   
  5  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"   "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"    "NO"  "NO"   
  6  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"   "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"    "NO"  "NO"   
  7  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"   "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"    "NO"  "NO"   
  8  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"   "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"    "NO"  "NO"   
  9  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"   "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"    "NO"  "NO"   
  10 "NO"  "NO"  "NO"   "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "YES" "NO"    "NO"  "NO"
```

where did I go wrong?

Comment: What is your expected output, a data.frame, a matrix, ......? because you are forcing a sparse matrix into a dense matrix, which if you use your function turns into a huge character object. Also this might impact your available memory if the sparse matrix is huge.

Comment: Actually, I don't know what output should it be, I want to use it as a input for naiveBayes() function. I've followed https://rpubs.com/drshah96/629986 tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `DocumentTermMatrix` as defined in the `tm` package, you can just set the count of each word to one, by replacing all values in `"v"` by 1 as so:

```r
dtm[["v"]] <- rep(1, length(dtm[["v"]]))
```

Full reprex:

```r
library(tm)
#> Loading required package: NLP
data("crude")
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(crude)

head(inspect(dtm))
#> <<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 20, terms: 1266)>>
#> Non-/sparse entries: 2255/23065
#> Sparsity           : 91%
#> Maximal term length: 17
#> Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
#> Sample             :
#>      Terms
#> Docs  and for its mln oil opec prices said that the
#>   144   9   5   6   4  11   10      3    9   10  17
#>   236   7   4   8   4   7    6      2    6    4  15
#>   237  11   3   3   1   3    1      0    0    1  30
#>   242   3   1   0   0   3    2      1    3    0   6
#>   246   9   6   3   0   4    1      0    4    2  18
#>   248   6   2   2   3   9    6      7    5    2  27
#>   273   5   4   0   9   5    5      4    5    0  21
#>   489   5   4   2   2   4    0      2    2    1   8
#>   502   6   5   2   2   4    0      2    2    1  13
#>   704   5   3   1   0   3    0      2    3    3  21
#>      Terms
#> Docs  and for its mln oil opec prices said that the
#>   144   9   5   6   4  11   10      3    9   10  17
#>   236   7   4   8   4   7    6      2    6    4  15
#>   237  11   3   3   1   3    1      0    0    1  30
#>   242   3   1   0   0   3    2      1    3    0   6
#>   246   9   6   3   0   4    1      0    4    2  18
#>   248   6   2   2   3   9    6      7    5    2  27

dtm[["v"]] <- rep(1, length(dtm[["v"]]))
head(inspect(dtm))
#> <<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 20, terms: 1266)>>
#> Non-/sparse entries: 2255/23065
#> Sparsity           : 91%
#> Maximal term length: 17
#> Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
#> Sample             :
#>      Terms
#> Docs  and for its last oil prices reuter said the was
#>   144   1   1   1    1   1      1      1    1   1   1
#>   236   1   1   1    1   1      1      1    1   1   1
#>   237   1   1   1    1   1      0      1    0   1   1
#>   242   1   1   0    0   1      1      1    1   1   1
#>   246   1   1   1    1   1      0      1    1   1   1
#>   248   1   1   1    1   1      1      1    1   1   1
#>   273   1   1   0    1   1      1      1    1   1   1
#>   489   1   1   1    0   1      1      1    1   1   0
#>   502   1   1   1    0   1      1      1    1   1   0
#>   704   1   1   1    0   1      1      1    1   1   0
#>      Terms
#> Docs  and for its last oil prices reuter said the was
#>   144   1   1   1    1   1      1      1    1   1   1
#>   236   1   1   1    1   1      1      1    1   1   1
#>   237   1   1   1    1   1      0      1    0   1   1
#>   242   1   1   0    0   1      1      1    1   1   1
#>   246   1   1   1    1   1      0      1    1   1   1
#>   248   1   1   1    1   1      1      1    1   1   1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, that worked. but what was my code problem?

Comment: @Mansoor, I don't know the problem of your code, i've checked the link you have posted above and am not sure what the person who has written this wanted to achieve, especially by replacing numeric values with factors.

Comment: So you think It doesn't need to be converted to factor?
I've edited my post, please check it again.

Comment: naiveBayes does work with 0 and 1, no need for factors and making it complicated